# How can I associate a queued job with a particular user in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, queue

I've built a system based on Laravel where users are able to begin a "task" which repeats a number of times, with a delay between each repetition. I've accomplished this by queueing a job with an `amount` argument, which then recursively queues an additional job until the count is up.

For example, I start my task with 3 repetitions:

1. A job is queued with an `amount` argument of 3. It is ran, the amount is decremented to 2. The same job is queued again with a delay of 5 seconds specified.
2. When the job runs again, the process repeats with an `amount` of 1.
3. The last job executes, and now that the `amount` has reached 0, it is not queued again and the tasks have been completed.

This is working as expected, but I need to know whether a user currently has any tasks being processed. I need to be able to do the following:

1. Check if a particular queue has any jobs started by a particular user.
2. Check the value that was set for `amount` on that job.

I'm using the `database` driver for a queue named `tasks`. Is there any existing method to accomplish my goals here?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you finally find a solution for this?

Comment: @Bahman Nothing elegant. I couldn't find any way to associate a queued job with a specific user. I took a slightly different approach. I made a `tasks` table, which stores the remaining count and a reference to the user. Then, on the queued job, I passed the `task_id` in. That job runs on repea and checks the `tasks` table. If it doesn't find the task record it's looking for, it stops re-queueing. So instead of checking if a user has a queued job, I check the `tasks` table. It isn't perfect but it's close enough for the time being. Happy to explain in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You shoudln't be using delay to queue multiple repetitions of the same job over and over. That functionality is meant for something like retrying a failed network request. Keeping jobs in the queue for multiple hours at a time can lead to memory issues with your queues if the count gets too high.

I would suggest you use the `php artisan schedule:run` functionality to run a command every 1-5 minutes to check the database if it is time to run a user's job. If so, kick off that job and add a status flag to the user table (or whatever table you want to keep track of these things). When finished you mark that same row as completed and wait for the next time the cron runs to do it again.

Comment: That's not what he's doing, and this does not answer his question.

Comment: @TarekAdam it answers how it should be done, not how he is currently doing it. The database driver wont last him long and other queue drivers don't really allow for querying data inside jobs. The solution is to use another table or cache to track it, which is exactly what I suggested.

Comment: I think the drivers should be kept as interchangeable as possible, and a status on the user may not be the best coupling to associate a user to a job.  "status" in the user table could mean just about anything when the next coder takes a look.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm aware of scheduling and chose not to use that, as I may need to repeat the task after a matter of seconds, not minutes. I appreciate the feedback. Perhaps I should explore my options, such as a long-running node script to process tasks instead of trying to make a queue handle it using delays.